# My Azure-pipiline fail with the message "Version 8.0.101 of the .NET SDK requires at least version 17.7.0 of MSBuild"

Tags: msbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, nuget-restore

I've encountered an issue with this Azure pipeline:

```yaml
trigger:
- integration

pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu-22.04'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

stages:
- stage: ContinousIntegration
  jobs:
  - job: BuildTestAndPublish
    displayName: 'Build, Test and Publish the app'
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    
    # Tâche pour mettre à jour MSBuild
    - script: |
        sudo apt update
        sudo apt install -y wget apt-transport-https
        wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
        sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
        sudo apt update
        sudo apt install -y msbuild
      displayName: 'Install MSBuild'

    # Tâche pour installer le SDK BlazorWebAssembly
    #- script: |
    #    dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.WebAssembly.Tool --version 8.0.2
    #  displayName: 'Install Blazor WebAssembly SDK'

    #- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
    #  displayName: 'Update NuGet'
    #  inputs:
    #    versionSpec: ''
    #    checkLatest: false

    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      displayName: 'dotnet restore'
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'dotnet build'
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
        workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'unit testing'
      inputs:
        command: 'test'
        projects: '**/*.UnitTest.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
        testRunTitle: 'Unit Tests'
        workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'dotnet publish'
      inputs:
        command: 'publish'
        publishWebProjects: true
        arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        zipAfterPublish: true
        workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Here's a snippet of the error message:

> ##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(/home/vsts/work/1/s/WebApp/Alurnet.Oniria.Encyclopedia.v7.WebApp.Client/Alurnet.Oniria.Encyclopedia.v7.WebApp.Client.csproj : error : Version 8.0.101 of the .NET SDK requires at least version 17.7.0 of MSBuild. The current available version of MSBuild is 16.10.1.31701. Change the .NET SDK specified in global.json to an older version that requires the MSBuild version currently available.

The NuGet Restore task is the one that failed.
I don't understand this problem because I know that version 17.9.5.7608 exists, as it's the one installed on my development computer (in VS2022-c). However, this version is not available for the Ubuntu 22.04 VM, which I chose for my Azure App Service (it's cheaper than using Windows servers).

My app is a [new pattern] Blazor Web App .Net core 8.0.200

This code is the last version I tried...

Comment: At the time of this comment, the [`'Ubuntu-22.04'` image](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/ubuntu/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md) has [.NET 8.0.101](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/ubuntu/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#net-tools) but not .NET 8.0.200. The image also has "MSBuild 16.10.1.31701 (Mono 6.12.0.200)" and "NuGet 6.6.1.2".

Comment: Is there a reason for using the `NuGetCommand` task instead of the `DotNetCoreCLI` task for the restore command? The `dotnet` tool has its own embedded copies of `msbuild` and `nuget`. In `dotnet` v8.0.200 the embedded versions of `msbuild` and `nuget` are v17.9.4 and v6.9.1.3, respectively.

Comment: On Linux and macOS, the "free standing" MSBuild executable is only available as part of Mono. The current latest version of Mono has MSBuild v16.10.1

Answer (score 0):

Since you build your solution using `dotnet` CLI based tasks, you should be fine by using the SDK alone and you can remove the step downloading and installing the standalone mono-based MSBuild.

If you have build customizations that require an `msbuild` executable to exist, you can rewrite them to use `dotnet msbuild` as a drop-in replacement instead to use the .NET (5+/Core) based version of MSBuild that ships as part of the .NET SDK.

I also suggest replacing the nuget restore task with another DotNetCoreCLI task that performs the restore command. But you can also remove that if you have incompatible projects in the solution since the `build` command now performs an implicit restore (when necessary) automatically for the csproj file and graph that you are building.

Answer (score 0):

Thank-you!
I've tried to changed the NuGetCommand command by the DotNetCoreCLI command and it works!

My Code is now like this :

```
trigger:
- integration

pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu-22.04'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

stages:
- stage: ContinousIntegration
  jobs:
  - job: BuildTestAndPublish
    displayName: 'Build, Test and Publish the app'
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        projects: '**/*.sln'
        feedsToUse: 'select'
        vstsFeed: '[...]'
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'dotnet build'
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
        workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    [...]
```

And It's good...

Comment: Is there any close/resolved button ?